# TikZ, avoiding uneccessary ad-hoc coordinates calculation

Tags: tikz-calc

I am wondering whether there would be a simpler way to get a similar figure:
 (1) avoid adjusting by hand the size of each coloured box,
 (2) avoid computing by hand the middle of each box from which the arrows are drawn.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def\constraint#1{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (ctr) {$\constraint{increasing\_max\_peak}$};
\fill[brown!20]  ($(ctr.south west)+(0.1,0)$)  rectangle ($(ctr.north west)+(2.07,0)$);
\fill[pink!20]   ($(ctr.south west)+(2.07,0)$) rectangle ($(ctr.north west)+(2.9,0)$);
\fill[violet!20] ($(ctr.south west)+(2.9,0)$)  rectangle ($(ctr.north east)-(0.1,0)$);
\node (ctr1) {$\constraint{increasing\_max\_peak}$};
\draw[->] ($(ctr.south west)+(1.085,0)$) -- ($(ctr.south west)+(1.085,-0.7)$) node[below] {\scriptsize \constraint{Condition}};
\draw[->] ($(ctr.south west)+(2.485,0)$) -- ($(ctr.south west)+(2.485,-0.3)$) node[below] {\scriptsize \constraint{Feature}};
\draw[->] ($(ctr.south west)+(3.35,0)$) -- ($(ctr.south west)+(3.35,-0.7)$) node[below] {\scriptsize \constraint{Pattern}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could for example use  `\subnode`s from the `tikzmark` library. Note this requires the addition of the `remember picture` option to the `tikzpicture` environment. That lets you use the anchors of the subnodes to draw the boxes and arrows.

You could also make use of the `backgrounds` library to avoid having to draw the same node twice.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  tikzmark,
  backgrounds
}

\newcommand\constraint[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node (ctr) {$\constraint{\subnode{i}{increasing}\subnode{a}{\_}\subnode{m}{max}\subnode{b}{\_}\subnode{p}{peak}}$};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \fill[brown!20] (i.north west) rectangle (a.south);
  \fill[pink!20] (a.south) rectangle (m.north east);
  \fill[violet!20] (b.north |- p.north) rectangle (p.south  east);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[
  every node/.append style={font=\scriptsize}
]
  \draw [->] (i.south) -- ++(0,-0.7) node[below] {\constraint{condition}};
  \draw [->] (m.south) -- ++(0,-0.4) node[below] {\constraint{feature}};
  \draw [->] (p.south) -- ++(0,-0.7) node[below] {\constraint{pattern}};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Importing the package amsmath (which I also need in my document) breaks the proposed solution: for some unknown reason the coloured boxes do not cover any more completely the three subwords.

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu Not sure exactly what happens, but remove the two `$` from the `ctr` node.

Comment: Yes removing the $ solves the problem.