# Draw connecting lines under text

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I would like to recreate a structure of the following sort:

[image]

I don't care too much about the look of the lines (they don't have to have 90°/rounded angles or those tiny horizontal lines at each end, I simply need to schematize the connection of elements in the text above). The only thing that's important to me is the cross and checkmark in the middle of each line. I have absolutely no idea how to go about this. Do I have to use tikz? Any help is appreciated!

Here is my MEW:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\begin{document}
[P [\ldots DP\textsubscript{\textsc{3sg}}\ldots[\ldots DP\textsubscript{\textsc{1sg}}\ldots]]]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related question using `tikzmark` package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448913

Comment: I believe the best method is to use `tikzmark` : https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark . Try to search on this site, and I think you will find that your question has been answered before.

Answer (score 7):

A `tikzmark` attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont} % for checkmark and crossmark symbols
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\tikzset{
  midway mark/.style={pos=0.25, fill=white, inner sep=0pt, font=\scriptsize},
  every subnode/.style={inner sep=1pt}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture, 
  every subnode/.append style={anchor=south}
]
  \node {\subnode{beg2}{A}\subnode{beg}{B}CDE\subnode{end}{F}G1234\subnode{end2}56};
  \draw (beg) -- ++(0, -10pt) -| node[midway mark] {\ding{51}} (end);
  \draw (beg2) -- ++(0, -15pt) -| node[midway mark] {\ding{55}} (end2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice: to run with `xelatex`, you need to apply the patch in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339975.

Answer (score 5):

It is also very easy with the `\ncbar` command from `pst-node`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{niceframe, dingbat, bbding}

\begin{document}

[\Rnode{P}{Probe}\textsuperscript{0} [… \Rnode{D1}{DP}\textsubscript{\textsc{3sg}}[…\Rnode{D2}{DP}\textsubscript{\textsc{1sg}}]]]
\psset{linewidth=0.5pt, arrows=|-|, angle=-90, nodesep=0.5ex}
\ncbar{P}{D1}\ncput*{\footnotesize\checkmark}
\ncbar[arm =18pt, offsetA = -2pt]{P}{D2}\ncput*{\footnotesize\XSolidBrush}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works as a charm!

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks perfect, but when I tried it it didn't end up looking like yours, it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/LeVECgg

Comment: Which compiler did you use?

Comment: I'm using Overleaf

Comment: `pdflatex` cannot make the computations required by postscript. So either you compile in the traditional way: `latex -> dvips -> pstopdf` or you compile with `xelatex`.